# Android, GridView, Click an Image to show full size

Tags: java, android

I want to have a gridview where an image click displays the image full screen without creating a new activity. I have the grid set up.

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

i think i need to use setImageResource(R.drawable.?);

but im just kind of confused. any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dialog with an ImageView to show this image. You would have to create a separate layout for the dialog and set it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new activity for that, a workaround could be to use an ViewFlipper and switch between the grid and an imageview when clicking on an image. Otherwise, I don't see any way to display something fullscreen with a gridview.